# Codename One Form.removeAllCommands() dosn't seem to work any longer

Tags: regression, codenameone, side-menu

We have a form manager system we have used in a number of Codename One apps.
This system includes a process for populating the side menu.
When the menu is updated removeAllCommands() is used on the form to clear out the current items in the side menu. Then the updated ones are added back in.
At some point in a recent update this function stopped working correctly.
There doesn't seem to be any error it just fails to work as it used to

Comment: It might be related due to the migration to the on top side menu. Did you try disabling the on top side menu using `Toolbar.setOnTopSidemenu(false)` ? Regardless we would need a test case to understand the exact situation where this fails

Comment: Yeah this is with the `Toolbar.setOnTopSidemenu(false)` set  
Test case is have an app with a side menu. remove a forms commands. see the side menu still contains the commands

Answer (score 0):

After using this code the commands are removed but the menu button still remains:

```
    Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(false);
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

    Form hi = new Form("Commands", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Test", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> {});
    Button b = new Button("Remove All");
    b.addActionListener(e -> hi.removeAllCommands());
    hi.add(b);
    hi.show();
```